# Initial topology

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis

I have read that for **all** $U \in \sigma (X, {f_i, i \in I})$ (initial topology) there exists a finite number of open sets $V_i$ in $T_{Y_i}$ s.t.

$U = \bigcap_{i\in G}f_i^{-1}(V_i)$ or $U = \bigcup_{i\in J}f_i^{-1}(V_i).$

I doubt that **all**. As I know $f_i$ may not be a bijection. So, we can have $U$ s.t. no $f_i^{-1}$ map onto it. Where is a mistake?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The family of finite intersections of $f_i^{-1}(V_i)$ form a basis of the topology, but in general, there are open sets that are neither a finite intersection of sets $f_i^{-1}(V_i)$ nor a union of $f_i^{-1}(V_i)$.

Consider the product topology on $\mathbb{R}^2$, which is the initial topology with respect to the coordinate projections.

The sets of the form $\bigcap_{i\in G} f_i^{-1}(V_i)$ are the open rectangles $U_1 \times U_2$, and the sets of the form $\bigcap_{i\in I} f_i^{-1}(V_i)$ are unions of strips $U_1 \times \mathbb{R} \cup \mathbb{R}\times U_2$. A ball in the Euclidean metric is not of either form.

Comment: Can you suggest a link to read why such intersections form a basis. Also, does ball belong to product topology?

Comment: It should be treated in any book on point set topology when the initial topology is introduced that the finite intersections of $f_i^{-1}(V_i)$ form a basis of the initial topology. Or that the $f_i^{-1}(V_i)$ form a subbasis of the initial topology, and then the general theorem that the family of finite intersections of members of a subbasis of a topology forms a basis of that topology. By definition, the $f_i^{-1}(V_i)$ are open in the initial topology. Hence the initial topology is finer than the topology generated by these perimages. But the initial topology is the coarsest topology for

Comment: which the $f_i$ are continuous, hence it must be the topology generated by the $f_i^{-1}(V_i)$. I can't give a link to a page in a book, sorry. Yes, the product topology on $\mathbb{R}^n$ is the standard topology induced by the Euclidean metric. You can easily see that the product topology is induced by the maximum norm $\lVert\cdot\rVert_\infty$, and then see that $\lVert x\rVert_\infty \leqslant \lVert x\rVert_2 \leqslant n\lVert x\rVert_\infty$ for all $x\in \mathbb{R}^n$, which shows the two norms induce the same topology.